# Kafka consumer not consuming the data produced into topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have to create a kafka producer that generates a sequence of numbers from 1 to 300. Each of the message I wrote have to contain information about the topic, a key and the value which is a the binary value of the value to write.

This is the code I've created:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import numpy as np
import time

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='Cloudera02:9092')

for i in range(1,300):
    value = bytes(str(i), 'utf-8')
    key = (str(i), 'utf-8')
    producer.send('PEC5', key = key, value = value)
    time.sleep(3) 
producer.flush()
```

The kafka consumer should read the producer and show only the value in the console.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from codecs import utf_8_decode

consumer = KafkaConsumer('PEC5', bootstrap_servers='Cloudera02:9092', auto_offset_reset='smallest', consumer_timeout_ms=10000)

for message in consumer:
    for value in message.values:
        print(value)
```

I am running 2 terminals, one with the producer and a second with the consumer, but I don't get anything printed in the console. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `auto_offset_reset` value is wrong in the `KafkaConsumer`, from the docs it only has two valid values `latest` and `earliest` and **Any other value will raise the exception**

> auto_offset_reset (str) – A policy for resetting offsets on OffsetOutOfRange errors: ‘earliest’ will move to the oldest available message, ‘latest’ will move to the most recent. Any other value will raise the exception. Default: ‘latest’.

So construct `KafkaConsumer` with `earliest`

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('PEC5', bootstrap_servers='Cloudera02:9092', auto_offset_reset='earliest', consumer_timeout_ms=10000,group_id='test-1')
```

Also add the new `group_id` when you updated the `auto_offset_reset` to `earliest`, because kafka will only reset the offest to `earliest` if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group. [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_auto.offset.reset)

> group_id (str or None) – The name of the consumer group to join for dynamic partition assignment (if enabled), and to use for fetching and committing offsets. If None, auto-partition assignment (via group coordinator) and offset commits are disabled. Default: None

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the code as suggested but is not working yet

Comment: @IsabelLopez add the consumer group with new value